# Use external .png symbol as \thanks symbol

Tags: graphics, footnotes, titles

How can I add an external symbol (e.g. `wineglass.png`) to be used as `\thanks` footnote symbol? I want to exchange the standard `*` with `wineglass.png`.

I'm currently trying

```
\documentclass[a4paper, leqno,xcolor=dvipsnames]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\newcommand*\wine{\includegraphics{wineglass}}
\DefineFNsymbols*{woexl}{\wine\dagger\ddagger\S\P\|%
{**}{\dagger\dagger}{\ddagger\ddagger}}

\makeatletter
\setfnsymbol{woexl}
\makeatother

\title{Title}
\author{Author\thanks{Institution}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you `\protect` your `\includegraphics` and size it appropriately:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{footmisc,graphicx}

\newcommand*\wine{\protect\includegraphics[height=.5em]{example-image}}
\DefineFNsymbols*{woexl}{\wine\dagger\ddagger\S\P\|%
{**}{\dagger\dagger}{\ddagger\ddagger}}

\setfnsymbol{woexl}

\title{Title}
\author{Author\thanks{Institution}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or make `\wine` protected/robust?